# how to disable ws-addressing in wso2 bps 3.0.0

Tags: wso2

Is it possible, and how, to disable ws-addressing in the call of partner link in BPS 3.0.0?

On Jira it seems that there is an option for doing this, but in the deploy.xml there is no feature to force it and neither adding the tag

```
<enableAddressing value="true|false"/> //default false
```

works

(jira reference: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-7600 is of 2010, but no evidence of the feature in the product)

Comment: According to the JIRA it is fixed in BPS-2.0.1 version. Should be available in BPS 3.0.0 as well.

"but no evidence of the feature in the product"

This is not working in BPS 3.0.0?

Comment: No in the eclipse editor I cannot find any option for disabling the addressing and even if I modify the deploy.xml by hand the server doesn't honor the tag and produces the ws-addressing header information that causes problem with the web service (I may have expressed the tag in a wrong way, but tryed to follow the issue syntax any hint on the current correct syntax to use? Maybe it changed from 2.0.1 to 3.0.0?)

Comment: Seems a bug in dev studio,created a jira https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BPS-250

Comment: Any hint on the correct format to set in deploy.xml as a workaround?

Comment: I've tryed with:

<invoke partnerLink="saveusws">
 <service name="mail:SaveusService" port="SaveusServiceSoap">
   <endpoint xmlns="http://wso2.org/bps/bpel/endpoint/config"> 
 <enableAddressing value="false" />
  </endpoint>
  </service>
  </invoke>

but the server always send the address info in header:

<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:To>http://158.102.29.146/work/mail/saveusservice.ph
p</wsa:To><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:0094249d-8848-4646-87a8-a2036335052c</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>http://158.102.29.146/work/mail/getProcess</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header>

Comment: The wsa:To gets interpreted by the php server as the method and there is no "To" method of course.

Comment: Check the following posts. http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2012/03/unified-endpoints-for-bpel-processes.html

Comment: http://keheliya.blogspot.com/2013/02/replyto-header-in-unified-endpoint.html